# Can a bot change the appearance of a initial message?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

Is it possible to change the appearance of a message in MS Teams by a bot?

I want to develop a small bot which highlights new messages (with or without replies) in red automatically within a channel. As soon as a supporter reply with something like `/assigned @John Doe` the initial message should appear in orange. And finally after a reply such as `/closed` the message should appear in green.

Comment: Hi @dannyyy, No, for plain text messages we don't have any options to change/update. Instead we can use adaptive cards.

Answer (score 0):

**Posting the Answer for better knowledge**

**Copying from comments**

No, for plain text messages we don't have any options to change/update. Instead we can use adaptive cards.